# Eclipse CDT syntax error on class declaration

Tags: eclipse, gcc, mingw, declaration, eclipse-cdt

Just installed CDT for eclipse, with MinGW gcc.  C program "HelloWorld" compiles and runs ok.  But tried adding a class declaration in a new .h file to it.  Syntax error on class definition.  Tried writing my own class declaration and using the new class wiz.

Have used many other C++ ide's other than eclipse.  Would like to use eclipse for team integration.  What's the eclipse secret to get class declaration to work?

Here's the errors:
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o src\main.o ..\src\main.c
In file included from ../src/main.c:10:

```
../src/Logger.h:11: parse error before "Logger"
../src/Logger.h:11: syntax error before '{' token
```

Here's the class header file "Logger.h" where the error occurs.

```
#ifndef LOGGER_H_
#define LOGGER_H_

class Logger {
public:
    Logger();
    virtual ~Logger();
};

#endif /* LOGGER_H_ */
```

Answer (score 0):

The project created in Eclipse was created as a C project, not a C++ project.  Hence the absence of support for class declaration.

Solution: Created a new project using C++ type, moved the code to the new C++ project, deleted the old C project, renamed the new C++ project to the desired name, and ran clean & rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

The indexer can get confused.

I did a Project->C/C++ Index->Rebuild and this cured the issue for me.